# How to get only one element from arrays

Tags: angular, ionic4

l have this data json

```
{
  "name": "AL_mazyunh",
  "day": [
    20,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "enDayName": [
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday"
  ]
}
```

l want take only one element from those arrays . example `enDayName` get only Wednesday . l used slice, but he shows only 2 element     `{{forecast.enDayName| slice:1}}`

Comment: you need `{{forecast.enDayName[0]}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply index the array:

```
{{ forecast.enDayName[0] }}
```

or use [slice](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) but with both `start` and `end` arguments, but this will return a sub-array, so you still need to index the result:

```
{{ (forecast.enDayName | slice:0:1)[0] }}
```